# Add a column recursively in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe, `df` that looks this way:

```
Year Colombia    Chile
------------------------
2006   9.5660    24.5576
2007  26.0079    10.9652
2008  16.0893    2.3721
2009  -5.1036   -5.0465
```

And I want to add two columns called `index_Colombia` and `index_Chile` so that in the first row `f(1)` the value is 100 and the value of the second row for `Colombia` is 100*(1+26.0079/100) and for Chile 100*(1+10.9652/100), and so on... so that we get the following df

```
Year Colombia    Chile    index_Colombia   index_Chile 
-------------------------------------------------------
2006   9.5660    24.5576      100            100       
2007  26.0079    10.9652   126.0079         110.9652
2008  16.0893    2.3721     146.2816         113.5974
2009  -5.1036   -5.0465     138.8159        107.864
```

it occurs to me that it is necessary to do with the `mutate` function but I do not know how to formulate it.... Can you help me?

Comment: It seems like `cumprod` would be useful here, but I question some values. For instance, `100*(1 + 9.566/100)=109.566` and `109.566*(1 + 26.0079/100)=138.0618` (sfsg), but `138.0618*(1 + 16.0893/100)=160.275`, not your values. Can you explain how you calculate `131.0156`?

Comment: Yes, @r2evans, your values agree with the ones my solution obtains!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to correct the errant numbers, for clarity. It's not just for you here, but so that follow-on readers who attempt to make sense of your question and the answers don't have to puzzle over why the numbers are different.

Comment: Thanks I already edit it.. I was wrong, actually you have to multiply by (1+ current value for each country)

Comment: I guess that my solution below does what you want, @ValeriaArango.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution creates not  2 but 6 aditional columns named "iColombia", "iChile","index_Colombia","index_Chile","index_iColombia" and "index_iChile", where "index_Colombia" and "index_Chile" are the ones that I need. Do you have any idea of why this happens? Do you know how to avoid the creation of those columns?

Comment: You are using a dataframe that has already `iColombia`... You should run my code with a clean `df`, @ValeriaArango!

Comment: You can use the dataframe I have just added to my answer below, @ValeriaArango.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that the dataframe I show is just an example and it can change. I need that no matter how many country columns I have i just get columns like "index_Colombia" or "index_Chile". Do you guys know how to get this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  Year = c(2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L),
  Colombia = c(9.566, 26.0079, 16.0893, -5.1036),
  Chile = c(24.5576, 10.9652, 2.3721, -5.0465)
)

bind_rows(df[1,],
 df %>% slice(-1) %>% 
 mutate(across(-Year, ~ 100 * cumprod(1 + .x/100), .names = "index_{.col}"))) %>% 
 replace(is.na(.), 100)

#>   Year Colombia   Chile index_Colombia index_Chile
#> 1 2006   9.5660 24.5576       100.0000    100.0000
#> 2 2007  26.0079 10.9652       126.0079    110.9652
#> 3 2008  16.0893  2.3721       146.2817    113.5974
#> 4 2009  -5.1036 -5.0465       138.8161    107.8647
```

Answer (score 0):

If my calculations are correct, then this can be done with:

```r
dat %>%
  mutate(
    across(c(Colombia, Chile),
           ~ lag(100 * cumprod(1 + ./100)),
           .names = "index_{col}"
    )
  )
#   Year Colombia   Chile index_Colombia index_Chile
# 1 2006   9.5660 24.5576             NA          NA
# 2 2007  26.0079 10.9652       109.5660    124.5576
# 3 2008  16.0893  2.3721       138.0618    138.2156
# 4 2009  -5.1036 -5.0465       160.2750    141.4942
```